# Helicopter gungod?

Tags: story-identification

For a book review, I am interested in degraded/devolved cultures; i.e., those that are the results of human colonies having lost the technology that produced them.
I am trying to remember the novel in which "the only food of man is man", since the indigenous life is incompatible with Earth life, so we can't eat it.  Therefore, we become cannibals.  I recall a couple of characters watching an old news video in which the narrator refers to a "helicopter gungod", 'ship' having become the word for 'God'.
Can anyone help with this particular novel?

Comment: Did you lose your old ID?  Why did you ask this twice?

Comment: I'm with Radhil. Do you need help with [merging your accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous)?

Comment: Not a dup as neither this question, nor the target, have an accepted answer.

Comment: I'm split. Almost certainly this is a duplicate, but there is that possibility that it's the same name asking for the same thing, but differnt people...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Same person. I'm going to merge the two questions.